# How to filter json string and get subset json in Java?

Tags: java, json, filter, jackson

Is there any way to filter nested fields in JSON string?

I have tried following using Jackson SimpleBeanPropertyFilter

```
String jsonString = "{"
              + “\”node1\”:{“
                  + “\”field1\”:\”00\","
                  + “\”field2\”:\”test1\","
                  + “\”field3\”:\”test2\””
              + "},"
              + “\”node2\”:{“
                  + “\”field1\”:\”00\","
                  + “\”field2\”:\”test123\”,”
                  + “\”field3\”:\”test456\””
              + "}"
          + "}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter properties by name",
                    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(“field1”));
mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, PropertyFilterMixIn.class);
mapper.setFilters(filters);
```

It is working fine but is there any way to specify nested fields like “node1.field1” in jackson or any other JSON library for Java?

**Input**

```
 {
  "node1": {
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2"
  },
  "node2": {
    "field1": "val1"
  }
}
```

**Filter**

```
node1.field1
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "node1": {
    "field1": "val1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use JSON path for this.JSON path allows to filter out parts of the JSON tree using expressions like e.g: "$.node1[0].field1".

In order to use JSON path you will need an underlying JSON library (like Jackson) and then this library (Maven syntax):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You could import Jackson as a base library into your project with:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**

You can get the whole node with some extras using JSON Path. Here is an example using this expression `"$.node1[?(@.field1=='00')]"`:

```
@Test
void extractParent() {
    String jsonString = "{"
            + "\"node1\":{"
            + "\"field1\":\"00\","
            + "\"field2\":\"test1\","
            + "\"field3\":\"test2\""
            + "},"
            + "\"node2\":{"
            + "\"field1\":\"00\","
            + "\"field2\":\"test123\","
            + "\"field3\":\"test456\""
            + "}"
            + "}";
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    DocumentContext jsonPath = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
    final JSONArray res = jsonPath.read("$.node1[?(@.field1=='00')]");
    System.out.println(res);
    Map<String, Object> composedRes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    composedRes.put("node1", res);
    System.out.println(composedRes);
}
```

This prints out:

```
{node1=[{"field1":"00","field2":"test1","field3":"test2"}]}
```

which is pretty close to what you want.

Comment: JsonPath will return only value "val1". It won't return whole node and I need whole node.

Comment: @GaneshKarki Please check if the updated answer helps you.